# Regex issue - asterisk after \d

Tags: regex

I'm using http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ to test my regex: `[+-]?\d+\.?\d*(e[+-]?\d+)?`. It's supposed to match floating point numbers. Currently it doesn't match `.x`, but I want to make it do that.

I tried changing it to `[+-]?\d*\.?\d*(e[+-]?\d+)?` (changed `+` to `*`) but that's an error. What's going wrong here?

Update: is it because everything is optional?

Comment: It looks like there's a bug in the tool, your regex is fine. Try it on http://regexpal.com/

Comment: @tpolyak If so it's most likely a bug in the AS3 implementation of regex (it's quite crap). I prefer [regex101](http://regex101.com), btw.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `\.?` to `\.` and it will work:

```
[+-]?\d*\.\d*(e[+-]?\d+)?
```

I suppose that the point is not optional.

But if you want to make it so, then describe it better with `[.]+`.

As @h2ooooooo mentioned it seems to be a bug in the as3 implementation of regex.

```
\d+\.?\d+ // works
\d*\.?\d+ // works
\d*\.?\d* // does not work
\d?\.?\d? // does not work
```

Answer (score 0):

This <del>will</del> *should* allow for matching things like `1.0`, `-.2`, `1e7`, etc.

```
^[+-]?(([0-9]+)|([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+\.[0-9]*)|(([0-9]+|([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+\.[0-9]*))[eE][+-]?[0-9]+))$
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your modified regex matches the null string, that is, it matches at any position of an input string.

Try this instead:

```
[+-]?(?:\d+|\d*\.\d+)(?:e[+-]?\d+)?
```

It makes there be two different branches in the subgroup; either an integer (no decimal point, the left side of `|`), or a floating point number with optional prefix but mandatory point, and 1 mandatory digit following the point.